# SSIS & kingsway – The value is too large to fit in the column data area of the buffer

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, webapi, kingswaysoft

Iam using SSIS with kingswaysoft to connect to dynamics CRM and execute an action .
the action executed within CRM is call to a  WebApi and it returns a json string .
in my SSIS i need to use the returned output from the action and make some business logic.
the problem is my json object is too big,i guess .it contains 2356112 characters.

I've set a large length of my output column but still getting the error .
[image]

Comment: Try setting the data type to `DT_NTEXT` instead of `DT_WSTR`.

Comment: Still the same error ..maybe i need to change the way I'am calling my action ..instead of using kingsway , i ll use a script component so i got more controle over the returned results .